# How to not indent the header of \subparagraph?

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I want the title of \subparagraph just like other normal section title, not indented, numbered, properly sized.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}


\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{}


\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {pictures/} }
\usepackage[space]{grffile}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs}





\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents


\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{one}
eee


\subsection{two}
eee


\subsubsection{three}
www


\paragraph{four} \hspace{0pt} \\


\noindent
eee


sssss


\noindent
\subparagraph{five} \hspace{0pt} \\

\noindent
ddd


ddddd


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: @jfbu The maketitle error can be ignored, the document is not minimal, but it is compilable. Imho better than just a code chunk or even chunks of code pieces you have to put together like a jigsaw puzzle. I prefer an example as posted. A real MWE would be great, but it needs knowledge and experience to provide one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard-coded in `\subparagraph`'s definition.

Removing all packages I get this working:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{%
 \@startsection {subparagraph}{5}{\z@ }{3.25ex \@plus 1ex
 \@minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries }}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{one}
eee

\subsection{two}
eee

\subsubsection{three}
www

\paragraph{four}

%{\tracingmacros1 % for finding out what happened

\paragraph{five}

eee

sssss

\subparagraph{THE SUB-PARAGRAPH}

ddd

%}
ddddd

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 37 secons late `:)`

Comment: @Fran but you did not include a picture `;-)` !

Comment: touché! ☠☠☠☠  `:)`

Comment: @jfbu thanks! how to number the subparagraph title just like others? and have normal size, in your picture it looks larger than other titles?

Comment: @Fran yeah it is pretty destabilizing when another answer pops up and shifts down your work right at the time you are to click on the "image insertion" link `:)` but folks do upvote @Fran's answer, I am leaving mine only because it has this bonus picture `;-)`

Comment: @user348472 I removed the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` just use it again. It is not bigger, I only used uppercase letters.

Comment: @Fran life is unjust isn't it `=:-)`

Comment: Do not worry, i can handle it, and even upvote you `:)`

Comment: @Fran don't upvote me, my embarrassment will have no limits (I did upvote yours in the hope to start the crowd funding ...)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subparagraph{%
\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{0pt}%
{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\subparagraph{Lores ipsum} \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```